# What is the sequence ActionFilter Attribute For Execution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

In ASP.NET MVC which action filter method is executed in sequence wise?

Can anyone tell me the sequence of execution of below method? From top to bottom.

I.e. 1st to last:

```
OnActionExecuting()
OnActionExecuted()
OnResultExecuted()
OnResultExecuting()
```

Comment: The order of stages execution seems correct, see Listing 2 in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp.Net MVC, ActionFilterAttribute abstract class has the following methods to : These action filter methods are executed by the following sequence,

1. OnActionExecuting() - Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework **before the action** method executes.
2. OnActionExecuted() - Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework **after the action** method executes.
3. OnResultExecuting() - Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework **before the action result** executes.
4. OnResultExecuted() - Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework **after the action result** executes.

You can try [this example](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/action-filters-in-mvc) to track the execution order

Further read - [Msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuted?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Answer (score -1):

The sequence you have it in is not correct.

```
OnActionExecuting()
OnActionExecuted()
OnResultExecuting()
OnResultExecuted()
```

There is some documentation here under the heading **Creating a Log Action Filter** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: This is wrong OnResultExecuting() is executed before the OnResultExecuted(). The link you provided in your answer correctly says. Please read it.

Comment: ah yes, I copy and pasted it incorrectly. Thanks for picking that up